# tkinter python maximize window

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I want to initialize a window as maximized, but I can't find out how to do it. I'm using python 3.3 and Tkinter 8.6 on windows 7. I guess the answer is just here: http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TkCmd/wm.htm#m8
but I have no idea how to input it into my python script

Besides, I need to get the width and height of the window (both as maximised and if the user re-scale it afterwards), but I guess I can just find that out myself.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

If you want to set the fullscreen attribute to True, it is as easy as:

```
root = Tk()
root.attributes('-fullscreen', True)
```

However, it doesn't show the title bar. If you want to keep it visible, you can resize the Tk element with the `geometry()` method:

```
root = Tk()
w, h = root.winfo_screenwidth(), root.winfo_screenheight()
root.geometry("%dx%d+0+0" % (w, h))
```

With `winfo_width()` and `winfo_height()` you can get the width and height or the window, and also you can bind an event handler to the `<Configure>` event:

```
def resize(event):
    print("New size is: {}x{}".format(event.width, event.height))

root.bind("<Configure>", resize)
```

Comment: There is also `root.overrideredirect(True)` (removes title bar)

Comment: This works as long as I have one monitor. How could I change the code to maximize only over one monitor, not across whole virtual desktop?

Comment: Excellent work, both solutions work depending on if you want title bar or not.

Comment: This doesn't maximize the window as you can see on the three little buttons in the top right corner. Using the whole screen is different from maximizing a window.

Comment: Setting a windows posiiton to 0|0 doesn't work on windows due to the title bar and other things with the window manager.
@jfs But the ```Tk.overrideredirect``` function does not remove it directly. It rather (on windows) tells the windows window manager to ignore that window completely and for that reason the window doesn't get a frame nor title bar.

Answer (score 124):

You can do it by calling

```
root.state('zoomed')
```

Comment: Worked on windows too, unlike root.attributes('-zoomed', True).

Comment: Worked in python 3.9 | Windows |

Comment: This will not work in Linux. See the answer of azeeman below.

Answer (score 46):

To show maximized window with title bar use the 'zoomed' attribute

```
root = Tk()
root.attributes('-zoomed', True)
```

Comment: It doesn't work only on Windows. It works on Xubuntu quite well.

Comment: Works on Ubuntu 14.04 - J.F better check yourself next time.

Comment: As others have stated, `'-zoomed'` is not available on Windows version.

Comment: Not working on Python3.6, Tkinter 3.8 on Debian unstable with XFCE.

Comment: @Sylvester Kruin: to be clear: `root.attributes('-zoomed', True)` works for me on Ubuntu 18.04 while `root.wm_state('zoomed')` doesn't.

Comment: @jfs I can confirm that zoomed works on windows if you set it using the win.state("zoomed") function.

Comment: This is the best answer these days, because the "-zoomed" attribute is supported since Tck/Tk 8.5 and Python is shipped with Tcl/Tk 8.6.

Answer (score 15):

I've found this on other website:

```py
import Tkinter

MyRoot = Tkinter.Tk()
MyRoot.state("zoomed")

MyRoot.mainloop()
```

This solved my problem.

Comment: Duplicate of @user3292534's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22482930/355230).

Answer (score 12):

The first approach is to use the `root.state('zoomed')`, but is not supposed to be universally available. It works on Windows, and on my Ubuntu machine. However, under my Arch machine it doesn't.

---

The second is to first get the *maxsize*, and then set geometry manually, like:

```
m = root.maxsize()
root.geometry('{}x{}+0+0'.format(*m))
```

This works on most machines, but not on all. For example, under my Arch the `maxsize()` returns `(1425, 870)`, while the real geometry of maximized window should be `(1440, 848)`. So, you also couldn't rely on it.

---

And the third, in my opinion the best approach is to use `root.wm_attributes('-zoomed', 1)`. It is universally available and seems to be the safest. On some machines in could zoom only by width or by height, but comparing to previous method, this one would *never* give you a window partly ouside of the screen.

Finally, if you want a fullscreen, not just zoomed window, use `root.wm_attributes('-fullscreen', 1)`. It provides a native link to window manager's behavior, thus working much better, than playing with `overrideredirect` and setting geometry by hand (which on some platforms could lead to unmanaged window, which could be closed only by its own interface or killing the process, won't show on the taskbar, etc...)

Answer (score 3):

The most pythonic is" `root.wm_state('zoomed')`, as mentioned by @J.F.Sebastian

Comment: Not working on Python3.6 with Tkinter 8.6. `zoomed` is not allowed.

Answer (score 0):

I recently ran into a similar issue where a library I was supporting needed to add Windows 10 as a development target also. Thanks to the information I found here, This is what we're doing now:

```py
class INI_Link:
    """A connector class between a value stored in an ini file, and a value stored elsewhere that can be get and set with two helper functions."""
    def __init__(self, getter, setter, varname, inigroup="Settings", inifile=''):
        """Remember that getter is called first to provide the default value.
        Then the ini value is read if available, if not the default value is used."""
        self._get = getter
        self._set = setter
        self._save = lambda value :inidb(inifile)[inigroup].__setitem__(varname, getter())
        self._load = lambda :inidb(inifile)[inigroup].get(varname, getter())

        #first load
        self._lastvalue = self._load()
        print(self._lastvalue)
        self._set(self._lastvalue)


        self._callbacks=[]
    def trace(self, callback, mode='w'):
        """this only traces for .value.set() not for changes to the underlying value in either location.
        if you never touch this again until .commit() at the end of your program, then it will never trigger until then.
        call .probe() to force to check for changes without returning anything."""
        self.callbacks.append(callback)
    def probe(self):
        """check for changes, if there have been any, allert all traces."""
        self._monitor(self._get())
    def __get__(self):
        value = self._get()
        self._monitor(value)
        return value
    def __set__(self, value):
        self._set(value)
        self._save(value)
        self._monitor(value)
    def _monitor(value):
        "helper to dispatch callbacks"
        if value != self._lastvalue:
            self._lastvalue = value
            for cb in self._callbacks:
                try:
                    cb()
                except:
                    pass
    def commit(self):
        """Call this right before getter is no longer useful."""
        self._save(self._get())
```

And then in the main window class's `__init__()`

```py
    self._geometry = INI_Link(self.tkroot.geometry, self.tkroot.geometry, "window_geometry")
        try:
            #umbuntu and others, not arch
            self._zoomed = INI_Link(lambda:self.tkroot.wm_attributes('-zoomed'),
                                    lambda z: self.tkroot.wm_attributes('-zoomed', z)
                                    , "window_zoomed")
        except:
            #windows and others, not umbuntu
            self._zoomed = INI_Link(lambda: self.tkroot.state() == 'zoomed',
                                    lambda z: self.tkroot.state(['normal','zoomed'][z])
                                    , "window_zoomed")
```

and then when the window is being closed:

```py
            #save zoomed state.
            self._zoomed.commit()
            try:
                if self.tkroot.wm_attributes('-zoomed'):
                    self.tkroot.wm_attributes('-zoomed', False)
                    self.tkroot.update()
            except:
                if self.tkroot.state() != 'normal':
                    self.tkroot.state('normal')
                    self.tkroot.update()
            #save window size in normal state
            self._geometry.commit()
```

Answer (score 0):

As the [official documentation of tcl/tk](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TkCmd/wm.html#M34) states for `wm_attributes('-zoomed', True)`:

> Requests that the window should be maximized. This is the same as wm
> state zoomed on Windows and Mac OS X.

This means that `wm_state('zoomed')` works **on Mac and Windows**, while you need to use `wm_attributes('-zoomed', True)` **on X11** to maximize the window.

Answer (score -1):

With TkAgg as backend this is the only combination that maximized the window without fullscreen:

```
win_manager = plt.get_current_fig_manager()
win_manager.window.state('zoomed')
win_manager.full_screen_toggle()
```