# Expanding a window upon activating python

Tags: tkinter, raspberry-pi, python-3.4

I'm using Tkinter and python 3.4 to make a simple program for a raspberry pi based smart watch. The only problem is I do not know how to make the window expand to full screen when I run the program, any suggestions?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Display fullscreen mode on Tkinter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7966119/display-fullscreen-mode-on-tkinter)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [tkinter python maximize window](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15981000/tkinter-python-maximize-window)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple project:

```
from tkinter import *
screen=Tk()
screen.attributes('-fullscreen',True)
screen.mainloop()
```