# python full gui screen on ubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu, tkinter, fullscreen

I am writing a program in Python on Ubuntu which cover my whole display screen but if I opened that same program on other display screen it is not covering whole screen. I am attaching both screen shots.

[image: Display 1]

[image: Display 2]

Can you plz help me that how can I overcome this problem which create auto whole screen on all types of display on Ubuntu

```
import ttk 
from Tkinter import *

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = Tk()
    root.title("APPLICATION")                                         # Program Objective

    mainframe = ttk.Frame(root, padding="540 445 540 445")
    mainframe['borderwidth'] = 20
    mainframe['relief'] = 'sunken'
    mainframe.grid()

    ttk.Button(mainframe, text="Exit",          command=root.quit).grid (column=60, row=3, padx=8, pady=8, sticky=W)

    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Maybe you get some hints [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15981000/2870069) or [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7966119/2870069)

Comment: You're hard-coding specific sizes in your app, why do you think the window should be different sizes on different screens?

Answer (score 1):

```
step= root.attributes('-fullscreen', True)
```