# tkinter, wm_state('zoomed') does not work on my app

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, customtkinter

I'm running `root.wm_state('zoomed')` on my GUI app but it's just slightly moving my Window towards the bottom right.

I have no clue why it's happening. Can anyone help?

Minimal reproducible example:

```
import customtkinter as ctk

class MainApp(ctk.CTk):
        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        
            self.title("Test Window")
            self.state('zoomed')

mapp = MainApp()
mapp.mainloop()
```

Comment: Cannot reproduce the issue in my Windows 7 with Python 3.8.16.  It is better to provide a [mre].

Comment: On windows and mac you can use `wm_state` on X11 you use `wm_attributes('-zoomed', True)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [tkinter python maximize window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15981000/tkinter-python-maximize-window)

Comment: I've provided an example, no idea why it isn't working. Maybe something in my system not letting it maximize?

Comment: Is your platform Windows?

Comment: Yes I am on Windows. I am using Python 3.10.11 on Windows 10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As `customtkinter` overrides `.mainloop()` and call `.deiconify()` inside the override `.mainloop()` if it is Windows platform, so the effect of `self.wm_state('zoomed')` inside `__init__()` is override as well.

You can delay the calling of `self.wm_state('zoomed')` a bit by changing that line to `self.after(1, self.wm_state, 'zoomed')` so it is called after the `.deiconify()`.

```py
import customtkinter as ctk

class MainApp(ctk.CTk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.title("Test Window")
        self.after(1, self.wm_state, 'zoomed')

mapp = MainApp()
mapp.mainloop()
```